# Get java version in csh (c shell)

Tags: bash, shell, csh

I need to get my java version using a c-shell script.
I'll need to put it into a variable and use it afterwards for some manipulations and tests.
in bash this command works:

```
local javaVersion=$(java -version 2>&1 | sed 's/java version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q')
```

but in c-shell, when I try:

```
set javaVersion=$(java -version 2>&1 | sed 's/java version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q')
```

I get

> "Ambiguous output redirect."

error.

Yes, I have to do it in c-shell, not Bash or any other language.

I searched this and other forums in the internet but didn't find anything helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way that should works for you as it does for me:

```
> set javaVersion=`java -version |& sed 's/.* version "\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\..*"/\1\2/; 1q'`
> echo $javaVersion
18
```

Changes are:

- Replace `$( command )` by `` `command` ``; the former is the recommended current POSIX shell syntax but has never been implemented by `csh`.
- Replace `2>&1 |` by `|&`; the former is Bourne shell specific, the latter is `csh` specific.
- Replace `java version` by `.* version`; this is not strictly necessary but eased my tests as `java -version` returns `openjdk version...` on my machine, not `java version...`

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful, for a construct like `|&`. (Also backticks are not recommended syntax, better to replace with `$()` as in the question)

Comment: @miken32 Explanation added. Note that using `$()` was part of the problem, definitely not something to keep.

Comment: Right, I saw your answer from the review queue and missed the part in the question about this being for `csh`.